# System.Text.Json deserialization fails with JsonException "read to much or not enough"

Tags: c#, json, .net-core-3.1, system.text.json

This question applies to custom deserialization classes for `System.Text.Json` in .Net Core 3.1.

I'm trying to understand why custom deserialization class needs to read to the end of the JSON stream even though it has already produced the required data, otherwise the deserialization fails with `JsonException` that ends with "read too much or not enough."

I read through Microsoft Documentation for `System.Text.Json` ([[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to)], [[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to)]), but couldn't figure that out.

Here is an example of the document:

```
{
    "Response": {
        "Result": [
            {
                "Code": "CLF",
                "Id": 49,
                "Type": "H"
            },
            {
                "Code": "CLF",
                "Id": 42,
                "Type": "C"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The DTO class and deserialisation method are defined as following:

```
public class EntityDto
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; } 
}

// This method is a part of class EntityDtoIEnumerableConverter : JsonConverter<IEnumerable<EntityDto>>
public override IEnumerable<EntityDto> Read(
    ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
    Type typeToConvert,
    JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
    {
        throw new JsonException("JSON payload expected to start with StartObject token.");
    }

    while ((reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray) && reader.Read()) { }

    var eodPostions = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<EntityDto[]>(ref reader, options);

    // This loop is required to not get JsonException
    while (reader.Read()) { }

    return new List<EntityDto>(eodPostions);
}
```

Here is how the deserialization class is called.

```
var serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};
serializerOptions.Converters.Add(new EntityDtoIEnumerableConverter());

HttpResponseMessage message = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
message.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

var contentStream = await msg.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<EntityDto>>(contentStream, serializerOptions);
```

When the last loop `while (reader.Read()) { }` in deserialization method is absent, or commented out, the last call `await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<...` fails with the `JsonException`, which ends with `read too much or not enough`. Can anyone explain why? Or is there a better way to write this deserialization?

**Updated** the second block of code to use `EntityDtoIEnumerableConverter`.

Comment: I was having the same issue today also, My understanding is that when you are deserializing, this doesnt move the position of the utf8jsonreader, so when you return, it still thinks you are at the start position and havent read everything, and it throws. I had to add:
while(reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                reader.Read();
            }

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When reading an object, [`JsonConverter<T>.Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.read?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_Serialization_JsonConverter_1_Read_System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonReader__System_Type_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_) must leave the `Utf8JsonReader` positioned on the `EndObject` token *of the object where it was originally positioned*.  (And for arrays, the `EndArray` of the original array.)
When writing a `Read()` method that parses through multiple levels of JSON, this can be done by remembering the [`CurrentDepth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.currentdepth?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonReader_CurrentDepth) of the reader upon entry, and then reading until an `EndObject` is found at the same depth.

Since your `EntityDtoIEnumerableConverter.Read()` method seems to be trying to descend the JSON token hierarchy until an array is encountered, upon which it deserializes the array into an `EntityDto[]` (essentially peeling off the `"Response"` and `"Result"` wrapper properties), your code can be rewritten as follows:

```
public override IEnumerable<EntityDto> Read(
    ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
    Type typeToConvert,
    JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
    {
        throw new JsonException("JSON payload expected to start with StartObject token.");
    }

    List<EntityDto> list = null;    
    var startDepth = reader.CurrentDepth;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject && reader.CurrentDepth == startDepth)
            return list;
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            if (list != null)
                throw new JsonException("Multiple lists encountered.");
            var eodPostions = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<EntityDto[]>(ref reader, options);
            (list = new List<EntityDto>(eodPostions.Length)).AddRange(eodPostions);
        }
    }
    throw new JsonException(); // Truncated file or internal error
}
```

Notes:

- In your original code you returned as soon as the array was deserialized.  Since `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<EntityDto[]>(ref reader, options)` only advances the reader to the end of the nested array, you never advanced the reader to the required object end.  This caused the exception you were seeing.  (Advancing until the end of the JSON stream also seems to have worked *when the current object was the root object*, but would not have worked for nested objects.)
- None of the converters currently shown in the documentation article *[How to write custom converters for JSON serialization (marshalling) in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to)* to which you linked attempt to flatten multiple levels of JSON into a single .Net object as you are doing, so the need to track the current depth seems not to have arisen there in practice.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tdVuCh).

Comment: Thanks! I'll raise this particular issue with documentation with Microsoft.

Answer (score 8):

Just a reminder for anyone using extension methods or any external calls to make sure you pass the `Utf8JsonReader` by reference, or you might get some unexpected errors even if it seems as though you're advancing the reader correctly. Use:

```
public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> ReadObjectDictionary(ref this Utf8JsonReader reader)
```

...and not...

```
public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> ReadObjectDictionary(this Utf8JsonReader reader)
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  Totally overlooked the `ref` part of the parameter in the Converter class.