# Deserializing JSON to an object - Whole object not being deserialized

Tags: c#, .net-core, json-deserialization, system.text.json, blazor-jsinterop

I am receiving and object from a JS calendar via JSInterop in Blazor. I have a C# interface and class that represents the JS object. A few properties are not being deserialized. In Particular the `End` Property.

Deserialize like so:

```cs
var currentEvent = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TUIEvent>(eventBeingModified.ToString(), new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive=true});
```

The incoming JSON:

```json
{
  "id": "c7d1fa58-af2d-4b7b-8040-e9c92ad61574",
  "calendarId": "1",
  "__cid": 43,
  "title": "Voluptas molestiae consectetur enim exercitationem reprehenderit error.",
  "body": "Aliquid iste dignissimos provident sit occaecati. Distinctio itaque maxime cupiditate quae nihil dolorem deleniti aliquid. Qui voluptas et qui.",
  "isAllday": false,
  "start": {
    "tzOffset": -240,
    "d": {
      "d": "2024-03-22T01:30:00.000Z"
    }
  },
  "end": {
    "tzOffset": -240,
    "d": {
      "d": "2024-03-22T04:10:00.000Z"
    }
  },
  "goingDuration": null,
  "comingDuration": null,
  "location": null,
  "attendees": null,
  "category": "time",
  "dueDateClass": "",
  "recurrenceRule": null,
  "state": 0,
  "isVisible": true,
  "isPending": false,
  "isFocused": false,
  "isReadOnly": false,
  "isPrivate": false,
  "color": null,
  "backgroundColor": null,
  "dragBackgroundColor": null,
  "borderColor": null,
  "customStyle": null,
  "raw": null
}
```

The C# Class:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumMemberConverter))]
public enum EventState
{
    [JsonPropertyName("busy")] Busy,
    [JsonPropertyName("free")] Free
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumMemberConverter))]
public enum EventCategory
{
    [JsonPropertyName("milestone")] Milestone,
    [JsonPropertyName("task")] Task,
    [JsonPropertyName("allday")] Allday,
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [JsonPropertyName("time")] Time
}


/// <summary>
/// https://nhn.github.io/tui.calendar/latest/EventObject
/// </summary>
public class TUIEvent : IEventObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CalendarId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public bool IsAllDay { get; set; }
    
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TZDateJsonConverter))]
    public DateTimeOffset? Start { get; set; }
    
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TZDateJsonConverter))]
    public DateTimeOffset? End { get; set; }
    
    public int? GoingDuration { get; set; }
    
    public int? ComingDuration { get; set; }
    
    public string Location { get; set; }
    
    public string[] Attendees { get; set; }

    public EventCategory Category { get; set; }
    
    public string RecurrenceRule { get; set; }
    
    public EventState State { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    public bool IsPending { get; set; }
    public bool IsFocused { get; set; }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public string DragBackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public string BorderColor { get; set; }
    public string CustomStyle { get; set; }
    public string Raw { get; set; }
}
```

The TZDateConvertor `Read` Method:

```cs
private const string TZDateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ";

static byte[] _date = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("d"); //"_date"

public override DateTimeOffset Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, 
                                    Type typeToConvert, 
                                    JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    switch (reader.TokenType)
    {
        case JsonTokenType.String:
            // A simple DateTimeOffset string "value"
            return DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(reader.GetString(), TZDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        case JsonTokenType.StartObject:
            {
                // A DateTimeOffset string embedded in an object { "_date" : "value" }
                DateTimeOffset? value = null;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    switch (reader.TokenType)
                    {
                        case JsonTokenType.EndObject:
                            return value.GetValueOrDefault();
                        case JsonTokenType.PropertyName:
                            var match = reader.ValueTextEquals(_date);

                            if (match)
                            { 
                                reader.Read();
                                while (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.PropertyName) { reader.Read(); }
                                reader.Read();
                                var propValue = reader.GetString();
                                value = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(propValue, TZDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            }
                            else
                                reader.Skip();
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new JsonException();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    throw new JsonException();
}
```

And example of serialized `TUIEvent` object(turned back to JSON for read-ability:

```json
{
  "Id": "7ef281a6-3086-479f-a630-9967e7449db6",
  "CalendarId": "1",
  "Title": "Magnam consequatur enim consequatur maiores non dolor.",
  "Body": "Eaque fuga tempore ab inventore porro iusto. Similique vitae ducimus voluptatem neque adipisci occaecati accusamus. Adipisci ipsum dolore laudantium. Et et quas quisquam velit adipisci et est.",
  "IsAllDay": false,
  "Start": "2024-03-10T03:00:00+00:00",
  "End": null,
  "GoingDuration": null,
  "ComingDuration": null,
  "Location": null,
  "Attendees": null,
  "Category": "milestone",
  "RecurrenceRule": null,
  "State": "busy",
  "IsVisible": false,
  "IsPending": false,
  "IsFocused": false,
  "IsReadOnly": false,
  "IsPrivate": false,
  "Color": null,
  "BackgroundColor": null,
  "DragBackgroundColor": null,
  "BorderColor": null,
  "CustomStyle": null,
  "Raw": null
}
```

Why is `End`,`IsVisible`, and likely others not being parsed/deserialized into the object??

Comment: I have noticed you're passing null to the C# model for properties that have not been defined to accept null ie. public string[] Attendees { get; set; } Maybe try to change all these properties where you expect null to accept null ie. public string[]? Attendees { get; set; }. I think there's an error being suppressed during deserialization stopping the rest of the properties from being deserialized.

Comment: Also may want to look at your enums since something doesn't seem right there - maybe try  [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))] public EventCategory? Category { get; set; } and do the same for state - for state I notice you're passing 0, pass "busy"

Comment: Your TZDateJsonConverter contains a comment indicated that it is intended to deserialize *`A DateTimeOffset string embedded in an object { "_date" : "value" }`*.  There's nothing like that in your JSON string.  Instead, the `"end"` property looks like `{ "tzOffset": -240, "d": { "d": "2024-03-22T04:10:00.000Z" } }`.  Could that be the problem -- that your actual JSON doesn't match what your converter expects?

Comment: @dbc I need to fix the code comments, but the property is here: `static byte[] _date = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("d"); //"_date"` I suspect something is wrong with that parser, because everything after `Start` does not seem to be deserialized.

Comment: @mattsharp Good catch. Thanks. I just set properties to nullable. Still, `End` is not parsed, but I have null instead of default values. This is a start...

Comment: @GisMofx You tried the string enum converter? As i mentioned before I think it may be failing silently and this is another link in the chain - apologize if it isn't this

Comment: Also if you want to try another parser why not try JsonConvert.DeserializeObject from Newtonsoft - may give you an error you're not seeing with System.Text.Json

Comment: @mattsharp Thanks. I'll take a look. I'll drop the enums out and I'm re-writing the Read method to be a little more verbose/explicit. (More like the MS examples). My hunch is that I'm not returning the reader at the end of the property and end of one of the nested properties and then the reader silently dies on the next property. (I'm returning too early)

Comment: I re-wrote the convertor, I needed to ensure that the `reader` was left at the last `EndObject` token for the property before returning the value. Enum converter is working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem** is that the `UtfJsonReader` is not positioned correctly at the end of your `Read()` method.  It should be positioned at the end of the **outer** object like so:

```json
{
   "tzOffset":-240,
   "d":{
      "d":"2024-03-22T01:30:00.000Z"
   }
} // <== Here
```

But you are actually leaving it positioned at the end of the inner object:

```json
{
   "tzOffset":-240,
   "d":{
      "d":"2024-03-22T01:30:00.000Z"
   }  // <== Here
}
```

You can confirm this by checking [`Utf8JsonReader.CurrentDepth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.currentdepth)  as shown in demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/geUcqq).  And for a related question, see *[System.Text.Json deserialization fails with JsonException "read to much or not enough"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62147178/3744182)*.

**As a solution**, I would recommend to simplify your code by first deserializing to some appropriate [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object), then mapping the DTO to the final `DateTimeOffset` like so:

```
public class TZDateJsonConverter : JsonConverter<DateTimeOffset>
{
    private const string TZDateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ";
    record Dto(decimal? tzOffset, ValueDto d) { public (decimal? tzOffset, string? d) AsTuple() => (tzOffset, d?.d); }
    record ValueDto(string d);

    public override DateTimeOffset Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        (var tzOffset, var d) = reader.TokenType switch
        {
            JsonTokenType.String => (default(decimal?), reader.GetString()),
            JsonTokenType.StartObject => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dto>(ref reader, options)!.AsTuple(),
            JsonTokenType.Null => default, // Remove if you don't want to allow a null value.
            _ => throw new JsonException(),
        };
        
        var value = d != null ? DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(d, TZDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : default;
        // Handle tzOffset somehow?
        return value;
    }
    
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTimeOffset value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Not only does this approach guarantee that the reader will be correctly positioned, it also results in code that is much simpler.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8mkDxU).

Comment: @GisMofx - there may also be problems with `JsonStringEnumMemberConverter` but you didn't include it in your question so I don't know for sure.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I ended up coming to the same conclusion about leaving at the wrong depth level, but my deserialization solution is a little more verbose. This is a lot cleaner and concise.